# HAProxy redirect scheme not working as documented

Tags: haproxy

I'm running HAProxy 1.4.24 behind LB.  SSL terminates on LB.  I want to redirect http requests to https.  I have following config:

```
log         127.0.0.1 local2
chroot      /var/lib/haproxy
pidfile     /var/run/haproxy.pid
maxconn     4000
user        haproxy
group       haproxy
daemon

# turn on stats unix socket
stats socket /var/lib/haproxy/stats
defaults
  mode                    http
  log                     global
  option                  httplog
  option                  dontlognull
  option http-server-close
  option forwardfor       except 127.0.0.0/8
  option                  redispatch
  retries                 3
  timeout http-request    10s
  timeout queue           1m
  timeout connect         10s
  timeout client          1m
  timeout server          1m
  timeout http-keep-alive 10s
  timeout check           10s
  maxconn                 3000

frontend  httpIn *:7258
  maxconn             100000
  option forwardfor   header x-forwarded-for
  acl is_http hdr(X-Forwarded-Proto) http
  redirect scheme https code 301 if is_http
  default_backend             app

backend app
 balance     roundrobin
 cookie      LBSTICKY insert indirect nocache httponly secure maxlife 8h
 server  app1 10.10.10.10:8080 cookie app1
 server  app2 10.10.10.11:8080 cookie app2
```

My problem is the line

```
redirect scheme https code 301 if is_http
```

which generates the following error when running `haproxy -f /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg -c` :

```
[ALERT] 026/210541 (8482) : parsing [/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg:67] : 'redirect' expects 'code', 'prefix', 'location', 'set-cookie', 'clear-cookie', 'drop-query' or 'append-slash' (was 'scheme').`
```

I rechecked documentation which says I'm using correct syntax for redirect.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`redirect scheme` is indeed not available in HAProxy 1.4.24. Right now, it is available in HAProxy 1.5-dev13 and newer as well as in HAProxy 1.4.25 and newer, including the [haproxy-1.4 master](http://git.1wt.eu/web?p=haproxy-1.4.git;a=summary).

The documentation you had a look at was probably the one [by Cyril Bonté](http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/configuration-1.4.html#4.2-redirect%20scheme) which currently is generated from the 1.4 master, not the 1.4.24 release.

As such, you could either upgrade to one of the named versions or work around the limitation. A common workaround is to use `redirect prefix` like this

```
redirect prefix https://domain.com if is_http { hdr(host) -i domain.com }
```

This rule has to be enumerated for each hostname where you want the redirect to happen.

Comment: Thanks!  I assumed they stopped development at last stable 1.4.24.  If anyone interested, here is the [source code](http://haproxy.1wt.eu/download/1.4/src/snapshot/) to compile from.

Comment: For those of you on Debian or Ubuntu like me, I found this site to be really helpful for setting up the correct apt sources for installation of newer versions: http://haproxy.debian.net/

Answer (score 3):

This option is available on HAProxy 1.5...
You have to use redirect location in 1.4 branch for this purpose.

Baptiste

Comment: I'm hesitant to use 1.5 as it is still in development.  I'm hoping it'll be stable by the time my app goes into production.

Comment: @r7p All software (or at least the one you want to use) "is still in development". Just because someone attaches a "stable" label on some piece of software, it's not more or less stable or usable than a piece of software without such a label. You would still need to test whether things work out for you.